# JMeter Non GUI : Not running for multiple users

Tags: jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I am using the below command to run the simple test using non-GUI mode. But by default, it is running for 1 user and 1 iteration .

```
jmeter -n -t <jmx file location> -l <Results file> -JUsers=5 -JRampUp=2 -JStepsCount=5 -JTime=300 -e -o <html report>
```

Please check the attachment for the settings i used and suggest.
Jmeter version: 5.4.3

I tried executing the in non gui mode for multiple users and it is running for only single user.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is looking okay, just make sure to reference the values you're passing via [`-J` command line arguments](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) via [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group):

- `${__P(Users,)}`
- `${__P(RampUp,)}`
- `${__P(Time,)}`
- etc.

Also consider adding `-f` argument to your command line, this way you will overwrite previously generated .jtl results file and the HTML Reporting Dashboard.

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)

[image]

Comment: I tried the command " jmeter -n -t DemoWebShop.jmx -Jusers=5 -JrampUp=2 -JstepsCount=5 -Jtime=300 -l \Jmeter_27APR\JMeter\apache-jmeter-5.4.3\bin\examples\results1.csv  -e -o \Jmeter_27APR\JMeter\apache-jmeter-5.4.3\bin\examples\htmlreport"  with sample parameters ${__P(users,)}, ${__P(rampUp,)} .But it is still running for single user only. PLease suggest if anything basic i am missing